# How to use layout() function in R?

Tags: r, plot

I just took an example which produces four plots combined with the `layout` function. However, I cannot figure out how the matrix inside `layout()` connects to the layout of these plots.

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 1,
                2, 3, 4,
                2, 3, 4), nr=3, byrow=T))
hist(rnorm(25), col="VioletRed")
hist(rnorm(25), col="VioletRed")
hist(rnorm(25), col="VioletRed") 
hist(rnorm(25), col="VioletRed")
```

Comment: According to `?layout`, `layout divides the device up into as many rows and columns as there are in matrix mat, with the column-widths and the row-heights specified in the respective arguments.`

Comment: Here it is a 3*3 matrix and has a figure with four plots. So how does these number correspond to the plots?

Comment: The best explanation of its functioning that I know sits in the [YaRrr! Pirate’s Guide to R](https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/arranging-plots-with-parmfrow-and-layout.html#complex-plot-layouts-with-layout). Once the basic reasoning was explained the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/topics/layout) suddenly made all sense.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For your example, the graphics device is split into a 3 x 3-cell grid, with columns/rows having equal width/height (since that is the default behaviour when you don't provide `widths` and `heights` arguments).

After calling `layout`, the first subsequent plot will fill the cells for which the matrix has value 1 (i.e., the top three cells). The second plot will fill the cells for which the matrix has value 2 (bottom-left and middle-left cells), and so on.

To get a preview of the ensuing layout, you can use `layout.show`:

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 1,
                2, 3, 4,
                2, 3, 4), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE))
layout.show(n=4)
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is perfect! Thanks

Comment: Perfect. Formatting the matrix in this way allows us to understand easily.