# save a multipanel plot in R

Tags: r, plot, r-plotly

I want to create a multipanel graph. For this, I used "[How to use layout() function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810854/how-to-use-layout-function-in-r)" to create the layout.

I have created a panel which looks like below.

```
tpan = rbind(c(rep(1,3),c(rep(2,3),c(rep(3,3),8))),
         c(rep(1,3),c(rep(2,3),c(rep(3,3),8))),
         c(rep(1,3),c(rep(2,3),c(rep(3,3),8))),
         c(rep(1,3),c(rep(2,3),c(rep(3,3),8))),
         c(rep(1,3),c(rep(2,3),c(rep(3,3),8))),
         c(rep(1,3),c(rep(2,3),c(rep(3,3),8))),
         c(rep(4,3),c(rep(5,3),c(rep(6,3),8))),
         c(rep(4,3),c(rep(5,3),c(rep(6,3),8))),
         c(rep(4,3),c(rep(5,3),c(rep(6,3),8))),
         c(rep(4,3),c(rep(5,3),c(rep(6,3),8))),
         c(rep(4,3),c(rep(5,3),c(rep(6,3),8))),
         c(rep(4,3),c(rep(5,3),c(rep(6,3),8))),
         c(rep(9,3),c(rep(9,3),c(rep(9,3),9))),
         c(9,rep(7,2),c(rep(7,3),c(rep(7,3))),9),
         c(9,rep(7,2),c(rep(7,3),c(rep(7,3))),9),
         c(9,rep(7,2),c(rep(7,3),c(rep(7,3))),9),
         c(9,rep(7,2),c(rep(7,3),c(rep(7,3))),9),
         c(9,rep(7,2),c(rep(7,3),c(rep(7,3))),9),
         c(9,rep(7,2),c(rep(7,3),c(rep(7,3))),9),
         c(rep(9,3),c(rep(9,3),c(rep(9,3))),9))
layout(tpan)
layout.show(9)
```

Now, I want to create a plot inside the each of the layout and save the final results as png. So the final plot should have 8 plots in it.

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0), oma=c(0,0,0,0)) 
png("a.png",width=5,height=5,units="in",res=600)
```

For the sake of reproducibility, I plot a simple repeated graph 8 times here
`plot(1:10);plot(1:10);plot(1:10);plot(1:10);plot(1:10);plot(1:10);plot(1:10);plot(1:10)`

```
dev.off()
```

This doesn't result in what I needed. This only outputs a single plot of `plot(1:10)` instead of 8 plots combined in a single plot. However, when I try to plot this manually in Rstudio plot window (without opening a png device) it shows all the 8 figures.

Can anyone help me with this?

I have some further questions regarding this.

1. What if I want to write a text in each panel `text("A.....",)` exactly at the center of each panel plot. How could this be achieved
2. Also needed to plot a box around each panel as shown exactly in the layout figure. I tried with `box("outer",colour="black")` and it only creates a box around the outer margin of the whole plot not for individual panels.
3. How can I move back and forth in the layout? For eg. how to call any layout(5) and do some replotting/adjustment with it?

Any help regarding these would be helpful to me.

[image]

Comment: you need to start `png` first, before layout or anything else; 1) `text(grconvertX(.5, 'nfc'), grconvertY(.5, 'nfc'), 'A...')`; 2) `box('figure')`; 3) `par(mfg = c(1, 5)); abline(h = 5)`; 4) please stick to one question per post

Comment: @rawr your third answer didnt worked. I changed the layout to `npan = rbind(c(rep(4,3),c(rep(5,3),c(rep(6,3),7))),
      c(rep(1,3),c(rep(2,3),c(rep(3,3),7))),
      c(rep(1,3),c(rep(2,3),c(rep(3,3),7))),
      c(rep(1,3),c(rep(2,3),c(rep(3,3),7))),
      c(rep(1,3),c(rep(2,3),c(rep(3,3),7))),
      c(rep(1,3),c(rep(2,3),c(rep(3,3),7))))
png("a.png")
layout(npan)
layout.show(7)
par(mfg=c(1,1))
text(grconvertX(.5, 'nfc'), grconvertY(.5, 'nfc'), 'A...')
dev.off()` instead of writing string to top (small) panel it writes to the bottom big panel.

Comment: `par(mfg=c(1,4)); text(grconvertX(.5, 'nfc'), grconvertY(.5, 'nfc'), 'A...')`