# How to customize base R plots and subplots in detail?

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

There is this figure in an economics paper:

[image]

I want to style my plots just like these -- with invisible top axis, Y-axis values on the right hand side, axis labels on the top of it and aligned horizontally, subplot titles aligned to the left and each subplot taller than wider and thus emphasizing change along Y-axis. I primarily use `MATLAB` and I tried to fiddle with it to reproduce something like this but in vain. I then reached out to one of the authors of the paper asking if he could tell which application he used for plots and if he could share how to style my plots after theirs. He responded saying he didn't have the code but he thought it was done in `R`.

I have not seen plots like this being done in `R` and even after hours of internet trawling, I didn't find anything `R`-generated which looked even remotely similar. Will appreciate if you folks have any thoughts/advice on whether it is indeed possible to do it in `R`.

EDIT

Courtesy of inputs by Isabella Ghement and after whuber's comments, I tried plotting one of the 4 by 2 panels in the figure in my question. Here is how it looks:

[image]

Ruefully, this is quite different from the panels in the question. Presumably, if I can get one panel right, I can then prepare a figure containing  m by n subplots. That said, this figure has only two elements that I want -- invisible top axis and subplot title aligned to the left. But its tick marks are outside, X-axis doesn't meet the two Y-axes and axis labels are still printed vertically beside them. Here's the code that produces the above plot (taken from https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html, thanks Isabella Ghement for the suggestion):

```
# specify the data 
x <- c(1:10); y <- x; z <- 10/x
# create extra margin room on the right for an axis 
par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 8) + 0.1)
# plot x vs. y 
plot(x, y,type="b", pch=21, col="red", 
 yaxt="n", lty=3, xlab="", ylab="", bty="n")
# add x vs. 1/x 
lines(x, z, type="b", pch=22, col="blue", lty=2)
# draw an axis on the left 
axis(2, at=x,labels=x, col.axis="red", las=2)
# draw an axis on the right, with smaller text and ticks 
axis(4, at=z,labels=round(z,digits=2),
 col.axis="blue", las=2, cex.axis=0.7)
# add a title for the right axis 
 mtext("y=1/x", side=4, line=3, cex.lab=1,las=2, col="blue")
# add a main title and bottom and left axis labels 
title("(a) Some Variable", xlab="X values",
  ylab="Y=X", adj=0)
```

I was hoping for simple way of generating such plots but seems like it's a lot of handiwork.

FURTHER EDIT

Though one of the authors wrote back saying he thought plots were in done in `R`, I do suspect at this point, like @iayork, that probably they weren't done in `R`. I looked at online appendix of another paper in which one of the authors of the paper in this question is a coauthor and that paper too has plots of similar style. Look at this plot for example:

[image]

When I looked at file properties of that plot (it's a PDF file that comes with online appendix in a zipped folder but contains no code), I saw this:

[image]

After seeing this, I immediately thought it was generated by `S-PLUS` but after spending hours on end, I didn't come across anything online on `S-PLUS` site or any other paper which bore any resemblance. And it was then that I thought it might not be that even though it seems like so by looking at file properties. And then as a last resort, I tried to contact the authors but couldn't get anything useful yet.

Comment: @AlexBlasberg, thanks for letting me know. Can I move the question there?

Comment: Flag your post, so that a moderator can move it.

Comment: I believe SO would quickly close this question because it hasn't sufficient detail: no minimal reproducible example, not even sample data.  With some fussing, you can generate this figure in base `R` graphics: no package is needed.

Comment: @whuber, the figure in my question plots the impulse response of various variables to a shock. They come from the model solution in the paper and I don't have data. What I am after is an example possibly with dummy data which can show if this type of subplots with similar style can indeed be generated in `R`.

Comment: Right--but you have to adhere to the rules of SO if you want to get good answers there.  Help them out by creating some sample data they can work with.

Comment: Thanks @whuber. I will soon edit my question and add an MWE.

Comment: This is an interesting programming question.  You will find a good starting point for answering it by studying the R code for "A Silly Axis Example" available at https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html.  In this example, dedicated to constructing a single one of your type of panels, make sure to modify the plot() command to include the option bty="n" (which will help suppress the top edge of the plot). Furthermore, make sure to modify the title() command to include the option adj=0 (which will help move the plot title to the left).

Comment: Of course, the strategy outlined in my suggested example will allow you to construct one panel at the time. You can then combine all panels in the same graphical window.  I am sorry I can't share the actual R code with you - the question was put on hold, which makes it impossible to add an answer at this stage.

Comment: @Isabella Presumably at some point this question will be migrated to SO or independently reposted there, so stay tuned!

Comment: Thanks, @whuber!  I saved the R code and if I get notified of when the question is migrated, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I just added an MWE to my question. The output from it doesn't go far towards where I want to be.

Comment: To my eye this looks like Python, matplotlib with some basic styling.  I think matplotlib handles subplots a little more easily than R does.

Comment: Thanks, @iayork, I just added more information which perhaps confirms what you think. I too think probably another application was used to do these plots. But even after spending way too much time chasing what was used to generate these plots and how they were plotted, I am still drawing blank.

Comment: The subplots, dual axes, and overall layout would be quite straightforward with Python/matplotlib. A little tweaking might be needed to get the text and titles identical. Getting the legend looking the same might be the trickiest part.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement, may be you would like to chip in with your code?

Comment: @VivekSharma **Hey** I think I definitely showed you a way in my answer how to make such plots in R. Since you are not satisfied, for me it's unclear what you're actually asking. Therefore I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

You've already deactivated the `yaxt`, so deactivate `xaxt` as well. In `axis` we can omit the labels with `labels=FALSE`. May I then introduce `mtext` with which you can create labels independently from the axis. Yes the inward ticks are done with `tck=-something`. To obtain the axes touch each other we start at `0` and end slightly higher as the maximum value, overlap should be hidden automatically. Add `legend`. Finally it's wise to use `png` device to obtain desired aspect ratio. I think that's it, in a nutshell?

```
# specify the data 
x <- c(0:10); y <- ((x^2)-20)/100; z <- (100/x-3)/100

# helper variables
t.adj <- .03
y.seq <- c(-.5, seq(0, 1.5, length.out=4))

png("ecn.plot.png", width=400, height=500)

# margins
par(mar=c(4, 4, 4, 5) + 0.1)

# plot x vs. y 
plot(x, y,type="l", pch=21, col="red", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(-.42, max(y.seq)),
     yaxt="n", xaxt="n", lty=1, xlab="", ylab="", bty="n", lwd=2)
# add x vs. 1/x 
lines(x, z, type="l", pch=22, col="blue", lty=2, lwd=2)
# add y-zero line
abline(h=0, lwd=2)
# draw axes
axis(1, at=(-1:6)*2,labels=FALSE, col.axis="black", tck=t.adj, lwd=2)
mtext((0:5)*2, 1, 0, at=(0:5)*2,col.axis="black", font=2)
axis(2, at=y.seq, labels=FALSE, col.axis="red", las=2, tck=t.adj, lwd=2)
axis(4, at=y.seq, labels=FALSE, col.axis="red", las=2, tck=t.adj, lwd=2)
mtext(formatC(sort(c(0, y.seq)), digits=1, format="f"), 4, 2, 
      at=sort(c(0, y.seq)), col="black", las=2, font=2, adj=1)
mtext("pct.", 4, 0, at=max(y.seq)+.15, las=2, adj=1, font=2, cex=.9)
# add title
mtext("(a) Some Variable", padj=-2, adj=0, cex=1.2, font=2)
# add legend
legend(x[2], max(y.seq), c("Home", "Foreign"), lty=c(1, 2), 
       col=c("red", "blue"), bty="n", cex=.8)

dev.off()
```

#### Result

[image]

Ah, for the arranging of multiple plots you may want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810909/6574038).